# Consolidator code - how to merge multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code which goes like this:

```
Sub GetSheets()
    Path = "C:\Users\DDC\Desktop\data\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Next Sheet
        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

This VBA code consolidates multiple excel into a single excel with different sheets. 
If we have 100 excels, running this code on an empty cell will consolidate the new empty excel with 100 sheets. 
For example, let's say I have 2 different excels with a similar format (containing the same headers) containing 10 rows of data each.

My requirement is that after running this code, I want the o/p excel to have only 1 sheet with 20 rows of data consolidated into one single sheet. I don't want 2 separate sheets.

Currently, I'm trying to do the same for 95 sheets, and if I have to manually copy each sheet into the main sheet then there's no point of that code.

Comment: You should give  sample of what merging code and data in your sheets you have and want to merge. Then this is still a hard enough to answer questions. Otherwise, its close to impossible to answer since merging could be all but simple in VBA especially if you want to do it for any type of sheet containing any type of data ...

Answer (score 1):

Please try  this code after reading the comments and possibly making some modifications to what is copied. The code will determine the width of each sheet of source data by the width of row 1 (presuming it contains captions for all columns). It will determine the the length of all columns by the length of column A (presuming that to be the longest one). Finally, it presumes that you don't want the captions repeated all over and therefore only takes the data from row 2 in each source sheet. All of these parameters you can set to suit your needs.

Sub GetSheets()
    ' 021

'    Const Path As String = "C:\Users\DDC\Desktop\data\"
    Dim FileName     As String
    Dim WsS          As Worksheet       ' Data source
    Dim WsT          As Worksheet       ' Data destination
    Dim Rng          As Range
    Dim Cl           As Long            ' last column in WsS
    Dim Rl           As Long            ' last row (alternating WsS and WsT)

```
' it's faster this way but you won't see what's happening
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set WsT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

FileName = Dir(Path & "*.xls*")
Do While FileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=Path & FileName, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each WsS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With WsS
            ' this finds the last used column in row #1
            ' columns to the right of this will not be copied
            ' adjust row number to suit
            Cl = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            ' this finds the last used row in column A
            ' rows below this (in other columns) will not be copied
            ' adjust the column name to suit
            Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            ' the range to be copied will start at row #2, cluding row #1
            ' which is presumed to contain captions
            ' adjust row number to suit
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rl, Cl))

            Rl = WsT.Cells(WsT.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Rng.Copy Destination:=WsT.Cells(Rl, 1)
        End With
    Next WsS
    Workbooks(FileName).Close saveChanges:=False
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Your request doesn't mention how many sheets there are in each source workbook but you code copies all of them and therefore mine does, too. Actually, the probability is that there will be only one work sheet in each workbook. In that case "All" means 1. But if there are empty worksheets as well, "all" may mean that there will be blank rows copied from blank sheets. I didn't make provision for this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :

```
Sub GetSheets()
lr1 = Columns(1).Rows.Count
Set target = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Path = "C:\Users\DDC\Desktop\data\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
With Sheets(Sheet.Name) 'change "A" according to your need - change 15 according to your need
lr = .Columns(1).Rows.Count
.Range("A2", .Range("A" & lr).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 15)).Copy Destination:=target.Range("A" & lr1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End With
Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Assuming that all of your workbooks data table has the same structure which start in column A, the code will copy each sheet in each open workbook in the loop starts from cell A2 to column P lastrow, then paste to the workbook where the macro is, starts from the last blank row of column A.

The code will fail if the data table structure not the same on each sheet of each workbook. For example: there is data table which start from column A to column D, and there is another data table which starts from column B to column E.

The code also will fail if there is a blank sheet in the open workbook in the loop because the code doesn't check first whether there is any blank sheet (or a table header without data) in the open workbook in the loop. For example : in the open workbook Sheet1 there is data, Sheet2 is blank (or only header in the first row but no data), Sheet3 there is data.

Comment: @BigBen, oops... you are correct. I change the code now. Thank you for the correction, BigBen.